# Can't update table X in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

I have a function to delete a single `post`, it works fine.

But when I have to delete multiple posts *(there are some scenarios, when I have to delete multiple posts together)* I call the function in query like

```
SELECT fn_delete_post(id) FROM posts WHERE ...
```

But I get this error:

> Can't update table 'posts' in stored function/trigger because it is
>   already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

FUNCTION:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_delete_post`(post_id INT) RETURNS int(1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE posts SET status = 'DELETED' WHERE id = post_id;     
    UPDATE table1 SET `status` = 'DELETED' WHERE ...
    UPDATE table2 SET `status` = 'DELETED' WHERE ...
    UPDATE table3 SET `status` = 'DELETED' WHERE ...

    RETURN 1;
END;
```

I know what does this error mean, I just can't think how should I change my logic as I have created many functions for different entities for re-usability perspective. I also have one to `delete comment`, which I call inside the `post delete function` *(not shown here)*

PS: I've edited the code just to show the scenario I have. Actual function code is much more complex and doing many other things. There are other questions for same error, but all have different scenarios.

Comment: Use a stored procedure for this, so you can iterate through the ids and delete them one at a time.

Comment: I can't call stored procedure in query. Are you referring to the `cursor`?

Comment: . . Basically, yes, although there are other ways of iterating through a set.

Comment: Actually I have cursors in stored procedures now. But they execute very slow, in compare to this `function in query` approach. But it just doesn't work in same table case.